# Phaser 2 - how to detect when I am dragging over another sprite?

Tags: javascript, typescript, drag-and-drop, phaser-framework

I am building an Phaser application where I have the ability to drag a sprite over the top of another sprite and drop it onto the sprite below it, at which stage my code will create a relationship with the dropped sprite and the sprite it was dropped on. I am not using any physics for this. This should add some context to the problem but the 'drop' is not the question I want answered.

Whilst dragging over the sprite I would like to alter the dragged sprite's scale to show the user that it is being detected as hovering over something it can drop into.

I could iterate through the sprites on screen and check whether the coordinates of the dragged sprite hit another sprite but that would be terribly inefficient to put in the dragUpdate function.

I'm looking for an alternative where I can raycast from the sprite's x/y drag position from the dragged sprite downwards and see if it hits another sprite. Any ideas as the docs are a bit thin in this area?

Comment: You're not looking for something like https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/overlap-without-physics ?

Comment: Similar, this was the function I wanted to call on drag stop, but I have an unknown number of sprites to run this check on which looping through on update or drag update really spins up the fans. Firing a ray down into the scene in one point would negate the need for a loop but I'm unsure if that is doable in Phaser

Comment: JSFiddle to help demonstrate the scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/trevburley/3ymgadvo/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle with some working example including down scaling of the sprite when it's dragged over one of the targets.

I loop each target and detect if the draggable sprite is inside the target.

```
function onDragUpdate(sprite, pointer, dragX, dragY, snapPoint) {   
        var draggableBounds = sprite.getBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i ++)  
      {
        var target = targets[i];
        var targetBounds = target.getBounds();
         var rect = new Phaser.Rectangle(draggableBounds.x, draggableBounds.y, draggableBounds.width, draggableBounds.height);
        if (Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(draggableBounds, targetBounds))     
        { 
          sprite.scale.setTo(0.2);
          if (!targetBounds.containsRect(sprite.getBounds())) {
                sprite.scale.setTo(0.5);
          }
          else {
            game.debug.text(sprite.draggable_custom_id + ' is over ' +  target.target_custom_id, 20, 20 );
        }    
    }
```

Checkout the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/22zpsbna/2/